# Using proftpd how do I disable regular ftp but leave sftp running

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, sftp, proftpd

We have a Debian Linux box with proftpd, we have both FTP and SFTP running, but we would like to disable regular FTP and just leave the SFTP running

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Actually you can have FTP and SFTP provided both by ProFTPd, depending on the configuration.

Comment: It's funny, I am just looking for a solution to disable SFTP but leave FTP :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used ProFTPd my self in quite some time, but remembered it having FTPS support.

So do you really mean SFTP or did you mean FTPS? The earlier being the SSH implementation of a protocol with similar capabilities as FTP and the later being FTP secured by SSL/TLS.

on a quick search I found the following document on FTPS in ProFTPd
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/TLS.html

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since this was first asked, but ProFTPD does support FTP, FTPS (via `mod_tls`), *and* SFTP (via `mod_sftp`) now.

And to answer the question, you can configure ProFTPD to:

- simultaneously allow [both FTP and SFTP](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html#SFTPAndFTP),
- *or* just [SFTP only](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html#SFTPOnly).

The same rich, configurable logging that ProFTPD does for FTP transfers is done for SFTP transfers.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using SSH as well. Most FTP clients will support it.  Also, if you add `/usr/libexec/sftp-server` (or whatever the path is on your system) to `/etc/shells`. You can grant SFTP access without giving full shell access.

#### VS-FTP is nicer than openssh's built in SFTP

One thing I do **not** like about openssh's SFTP protocol is, by default, it does not log transfers.  If you need to log transfers, then you may want to check into VS-FTP.  I am pretty sure VS-FTP supports FTP over SSL and SFTP as well as transfer logging.  VS-FTP is default on Red Hat 5, I think.